# android making listview place in scrollview container

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview

recently I have read  [this](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt) tutorial from roman nurik and after downloading its source code and making some changes by adding a simple  Listview instead of Item.Bottom view , I find out that Listview is not placing in its own container in custom scrollView . Actually depended on its height , it goes up and covers Item.top (with purple color in this sample and 300dp height )

here is screenshot . compare it to orginal screenshot in [this](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt) link  [image: what happend]
but it should be like this , and listview must be in that red place and covers purple one when we scroll it
[image: what I want]

is there Any idea how can I handle this ? (adding listview inside scrollview without conflicting )?

Comment: You shouldn't have a ListView inside a ScrollView, and you will find many answers to that effect on SO. A ListView takes care of its own scrolling. When you put one inside another scrolling container, it causes the ListView to load all of its rows to fill out the infinite container of the ScrollView. I've seen one post that purports to overcome this, but I can't find it, and I cannot attest to its efficacy. It was a "hacky" solution, at best.

Comment: I think the simplest solution for you is to move the contents of the ListView into the ScrollView, and maintain that as your sole scrolling container. This would be simple enough if the ListView items are a static set.

Comment: @MikeM. i don't understand what it means , how can i move contents to parent scrollview ?

Comment: You would have to do it "manually".  Instead of feeding a layout and a list of objects to an Adapter, you would need to construct the rows yourself. If your ListView contains a list that does not change, you could do this in the layout for the ScrollView. If this list is as you have it in the image, i.e. a list of single-line texts, just put a bunch of TextViews at the bottom of your ScrollView layout. Otherwise, you will need to do it in code. It's hard to tell what your aim is exactly from your sample image.

Comment: @MikeM. i got the point . thanks . 
Actually all i want is something like Music tracks listview in Google Play Music's App . when you scroll lists it moves over the cover image ..